# Tufte-book, ifplatform and bibentry warning

Tags: tufte

With the `tufte-book` class and this MWE

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

I get two warnings:

```
Package ifplatform Warning: shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
```

Second one:

```
Package bibentry Warning: You have used \nobibliography* 
(bibentry) without a following \bibliography.
```

On the other hand, these lines work without any warnings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

Who has an idea what is causing the warnings and how to avoid them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! These warnings come from packages used by the class. You can ignore them. Btw: The first warning can be avoided by using `--shell-escape` as parameter for your latex compiler.

Comment: although don't use `--shell-escape` just to avoid the warning (and only use it on trusted files)

Answer (score -1):

You can fix the bibliography warnings with the nobib option:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
```

A crude way to also get rid of the `ifplatform` warning is using the `silence` package:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[ifplatform]
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
```

Line 1 loads the package, using `\RequirePackage` as `\usepackage` isn't allowed before `\documentclass`.

Line 2 disables all warnings from `ifplatform`.